# Download Directories on uTorrent Web API

Tags: api, bittorrent

I haven't been able to find a definitive answer on what the "Download Directories" is on the uTorrent WebAPI. I wasn't able to find any Web API calls to specify a download directory and when I use the uTorrent Web API I want to be able to specify the folder they are being downloaded into.

Currently I just have them all start the download into a single folder, but I really don't like doing that. So I was looking at ways to accomplish this with the Web API but I didn't see any calls.

When looking at the uTorrent settings I saw that it had an option for "Download Directorie**s**", I currently have one directory specified here and everything goes here, but I am able to add more than one directory. I don't know how uTorrent decides which directory to put it inn, but is there a way for me to specify two separate download locations using the Web API?
[image: Picture]

Comment: Not a security related question. Please ask your question on other forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there a way for me to specify two separate download locations using the Web API?

No.

> **Limitations - WebAPI**
>
> Last Updated: Jun 02, 2014 12:00PM PDT
>
> It is not possible to specify a path to save a torrent's data. It is
>   possible to set the default download directory with getsettings, but
>   not for each individual torrent. This will be rectified in a later
>   release.

[uTorrent | Limitations - WebAPI](http://help.utorrent.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1573954-limitations---webapi)

Comment: Thank you, any chance setting the default download directory before each torrent and then changing it back after the successful start of each torrent would work as a solution?